# Dynamically adding User Control in windows form application

Tags: c#

I am developing windows form application.
Please find the screenashot so that I can explain my query.

[image: screenshot]

My requirement is, on clicking 'Add Row' Button, one more row containing fields like 'Student Name,No,Marks,Average' should gets added and upon adding it successfully, rest existing controls should automatically adjust their positions properly.

Please suggest me nest approach to achieve the same.

Comment: You can set positions of controls dynamically, but this type of design may cause you issues in the future. Will you ever have to handle 10 or even 100 students in the future? What happens to your form at that point? You may want to consider using a `DataGrid` or something similar that can have a static size.

Comment: I did something like this once, I would suggest that dynamic implementation too. In event of having too many rows there, you should put the rows in a panel and link a scroll bar to the panel so that if the number of rows goes too high the panel would just get scrolled.

Comment: Thanks grovesNL and Vahid.

Comment: @grovesNL : Can you pleae let me know mechanism though which we can have dataGridView that can contan textboxes that accepts user inputted values.

Comment: @Vahid : I have created user control and added it in Panel but after adding another user control on button click, its position is not getting adjusted properly.Is there any way to properly adjust these.I tried with Flowlayout Panel but did not help me.

Comment: @Mandar: You would have the same setup as shown above for all other controls, except you would replace the table of students with a `DataGrid` control. This control would allow you to use scrollbars as you add new rows. So you would have a button on the right for "Add Row", then perhaps have a prompt that lets you edit the row values before adding it, or something like that... There are many examples online, such as this example from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee344869(v=vs.110).aspx) which almost has the exact same setup as yours.

Comment: @Mandar: Well what I did for the positioning was to manually work with the 'x' and 'y' parameters. I set all of 'x's the same number, like 10, and played with 'y' for putting the components under eachother. Remember when you set the panel as their parent object, the coordinates will be met according to the left top corner of the panel, not your form.